# VB6: Why is Picturebox.Print() hidden from the Object catalogue?

Tags: vb6, picturebox, objectbrowser

the title already tells the question:
you can successfully call the Print-Method on a PictureBox-instance. But it is not shown in the object browser.

same applies for some other methods, `Pset()` for example is listed but the syntax is not completely correct.

**Edit:** The methods `Ubound()` and `LBound()` for inspection of array bounds is not listed anywhere. And in the IDE, auto-completion doesn't show it as tooltip either.

Does anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: Only actual class members are listed.  Statements like these get translated to method calls, which may be on other interfaces of the object in question.  We can't see the method underlying `Print` because we have no type library reference for that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the VB methods and functions from back in the day (like stuff that was available in QuickBasic or PDS or GWBasic) never appeared in the intellisense.  Not sure why.  Maybe because they are not on any object tree but static functions long ago defined in the runtime.  Then again, I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Hehe i thought the same. I've been using QB as well. Good idea they ported some useful functions to objects but they should've documented them. Regards